# Recover application after it becomes unresponsive

Tags: spotlight, performance, console, textmate, macos

Is there any way to recover an application once it freezes aside from killing it?

---

Context being, I have been working on a couple of files in TextMate 1.5 and TextMate has stopped responding, I have not saved these files, and I really do not want to loose the work.  I've killed all other running applications and have let the computer idle for quite some time but TextMate still remains unresponsive.

Before it froze I was conducting a simple regex search query within TextMate.  The files were only about 2kb in size.

[image]

Comment: There is nothing you can do to recover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also depends on why it's freezing too. I'm purely speaking from a Mac perspective here, but when something like that happens regularly I tend to delve into the logs to see what's up.

(Usually it's XPC up to its usual)..

If you're not a Mac user, without Windows infant of me, I can't give you exact steps, but here it goes for both to see what's up!

Mac:

1. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to get Spotlight up
2. Type in `console` (press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

That is the log "viewer" as such for Mac.

On Windows, off the top of my head and should apply from Windows XP onwards!

1. Click on the Start button
2. Click on "Run"
3. In Run dialog box, type in `eventvwr.msc` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

That's the Windows logging system.

If you're on Linux, then I suggest you watch `/var/log/messages.log` to see what's happening there.

Anyway, have a look into what's showing up in the log when it decides to crash and let us know!

Comment: Hey Adrian, thanks for the detailed answer. I'm familiar with Console but honestly, I usually find that the information it provides is jibberish to me other than to tell me that I'm s.o.l.. lol  I posted a screenshot of the Console log related to Textmate in my question.  Would you mind taking a look?

Comment: Can you expand a bit on the "CFBundleTypeController" line? I need the second ha;f of it :) Just looking at the copy of text mate I've downloaded the "CFBundleTypeRole" deals with filetypes, but without seeing exactly what it's nagging about, I can'y say for sure as to why its grumpy.

Comment: Sorry I meant NSBundleTypeController! I just noticed that autocorrect zapped me! :D

Comment: 10-31-14 2:50:24.385 pm TextMate[23449]: NSDocumentController Info.plist warning: The values of CFBundleTypeRole entries must be 'Editor', 'Viewer', 'None', or 'Shell'.

Comment: They all say that ^ and scrolling up, I notice there are hundreds of entries of that repeatedly.  :/

Comment: Right from what I can see on your screenshot and from what I see in the version of text mate I've just downloaded, something in the info.plist under "URL types" or "CFBundleDocumentTypes" if you look at the info.plist as a plain text XML file.

(right click on textmate, click on "show package contents".. Then go into Contents. If you open the info.plist, thats where the issue is.

it's HIGHLY unlikely the app mysteriously changed itself and sounds more like spotlight has thrown a hissy fit and spat it out.

Comment: In that "goliath list" which we just spoke about. In there somewhere is a bad entry... if not, then its, as I said, spotlight being grumpy. I'll try find a post I made a few hours ago as to how to sort spotlight out. Its a quick nifty fix too :)

Comment: Thanks, please do.  I think I'm going to open up a ticket on the  Textmate maillist as well, as this happens far too frequently.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151311/finder-search-doesnt-work-properly-after-yosemite-update/154167#154167

That resets "spotlight" which has ALOT to do with how Mac's interact with various apps/files.. Read it through before you do it as it throws your mac into "jump jet mode" as I call it, so you;ll be sitting listening to fans for 5-10 mins :D lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18333/discussion-between-adrian-sluyters-and-dcc).

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no way to kick start a application once it is locked (frozen).

Your only hope is you had the auto-save enabled in TextMate.