# Finder search doesn't show results

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight, search

[image: Finder Screenshot]

When I search in Finder there are no results.

- There are no results as I am typing, nor after pressing <kbd>return</kbd>.
- There is no loading spinner which usually appears at the bottom of the window.
- The loading cursor will sometimes appear, while hovering over the Finder window, after attempting a search.
- Spotlight searches work with no problems.
- On another account, both Finder searches and Spotlight searches work fine.

**My troubleshooting:**

- I rebuilt Spotlight's index for the entire Mac, relaunched Finder, restarted, but there was no change.
- I trashed Finder's plist (com.apple.finder.plist) and relauched Finder to no effect.
- I reset Spotlight with the "sudo" method in Terminal [mentioned here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151311/finder-search-doesnt-work-properly-after-yosemite-update), relaunched Finder but it didn't have any effect.

**Specs:**

iMac, 2009
Processor: 2.8 GHz Intel Core i7
Memory: 8GB
Storage: 1TB SATA Disk
OS X Yosemite 10.10.3
Finder Version 10.10.4

Comment: did you reset/restart the Finder ?

Comment: Start out by force-restarting finder. Alt+Click the finder dock icon and click relaunch

Comment: Perhaps a restart might do it. [This seems to be the same problem](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6602756)

Comment: I relaunched Finder and restarted with no change.

Comment: I reset Spotlight with the "sudo" method in Terminal (mentioned here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151311/finder-search-doesnt-work-properly-after-yosemite-update), relaunched Finder but it didn't have any effect.